# What's the replacment for Microsoft.Web.Services3.dll in .NET 4.x?

Tags: web-services, asp.net-4.0

I have an app used Microsoft.Web.Services3 before. Now I want to move this app to .NET 4.x. What's the replacment for Microsoft.Web.Services3.dll in .NET 4.x?

or I should keep the assembly Microsoft.Web.Services3.dll and the reference to it in my app even I use .NET 4.x?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider [migrating your WSE Web Services to WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732008.aspx).  That article says

> The benefits of migrating WSE 3.0 Web services to Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) include improved performance and the support of additional transports, additional security scenarios, and WS-* specifications. A Web service that is migrated from WSE 3.0 to WCF can experience up to a 200% to 400% performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Web.Services3.dll is part of the obsolete WSE 3.0.

There is no direct replacement. You should rewrite the service to use WCF.