# Is there a way to block/delete/hide a small portion of a .dll file that is causing my .aspx page to break?

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, dll

I have an asp.net website on a HostGator shared windows server (set at medium trust) that uses the Amazon Web Services. It uses a .dll file called `Microsoft.Web.Services3.dll`

I do not know how .dll files work, but somewhere inside, there is an instance of `System.Reflection` that requires a trust level full. This is the only line that is breaking my website and yet I need the .dll to get the `Microsoft.Web.Services3` namespaces imported.

Does anyone have any experience with .dll files that can help me get past this problem? I am happy to provide any extra information that might be useful!

Comment: If you need it, then you can't "block" it. It doesn't get called by itself, it's something you use from it.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649645/whats-the-replacment-for-microsoft-web-services3-dll-in-net-4-x.  Maybe you need to think about reworking some of your code?